# How to prevent IBM Watson Campaign Automation aka Silverpop from inserting text before preview line

Tags: html, css, html-email

Watson Campaign Automation aka Silverpop inserts "You're receiving this email as a test email. Some contents may not display or behave properly." which then populates in the preview line area in an email client, preventing our QA'ers from being able to read what the preview line says.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dXii.png) of what I am talking about. You can see that the inserted text is hindering your ability to read the preview text.

This only happens when sending a test. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to prevent the inserted text from being added when sending a test.

I've done extensive research but I can't find anything on this subject.

If I could find some way to prevent Watson Campaign Automation aka Silverpop from inserting this line, our QA'ers could see what the preview line looks like prior to sending, without the inserted text getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer: Create a test list, assign that list to your campaign and then deploy to that list.**

At a previous company, we had this same issue. 
Eventually, we figured out that the only fix is to set up a test list of contacts, assign that to the campaign and then send/deploy.
In our case, we set up a test list consisting of my team's email addresses and anytime we used this process to do a final check, we all received the test and reviewed accordingly.

To be honest, all emails should be tested in as close to live conditions as possible. 
Deploying an email to a test list, is the best way to mimic a live deployment.
This process is the best way to ensure your ESP is giving you the most accurate preview of what it will send to your subscribers.